# How to apply CSS to half of a point feature?

Tags: css, openlayers

Due to I can not use server-side StyledLayerDescriptor (SLD) coding, neither I want to load external graphics I would like to use CSS to style my OpenLayers' point features.
In detail I would like to fill half (or 1/3) of a point feature with different colors.

A CSS code might be

```
#OpenLayers\.Geometry\.Point_111{
  fill: red !important;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ce275f 50%, #1e5799 50%, #207cca 50%, #7db9e8 100%) !important; /* FF3.6+ */
}
```

[image]

The feature is not assigned to a  class.
Is that possible? Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Rephrase your question, post your coding, and a picture is always helpful in getting the point across.

Comment: You can skip the first paragraph. Go straight to the question.

Comment: what do you have so far? if you post your css we can suggest additions to solve your problem. as of yet we don't know your mark up OR your css

Comment: Seriously, this a general question. It does not need any code. I would be way nicer if you could first make comments in a more constructive way than shooting with negative reputations. Many thanks.

Comment: @ImagineWebDesign, SleekGeek, atmd Might wanna remove your -1's as the question has been reworded and is now understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I immediately thought of this:

```
.circle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;

    background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #000000 1%, #000000 50%, #ff00ff 50%, #ff00ff 100%, #ff00ff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(1%,#000000), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(50%,#ff00ff), color-stop(100%,#ff00ff), color-stop(100%,#ff00ff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #000000 1%,#000000 50%,#ff00ff 50%,#ff00ff 100%,#ff00ff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #000000 1%,#000000 50%,#ff00ff 50%,#ff00ff 100%,#ff00ff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #000000 1%,#000000 50%,#ff00ff 50%,#ff00ff 100%,#ff00ff 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #000000 1%,#000000 50%,#ff00ff 50%,#ff00ff 100%,#ff00ff 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ff00ff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/270dc91r/)

Gradient generated with [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: a good example, thank you. Unfortunately it does not work in my case. I tried also with inserting "!important" to each line. Nothing. How could the code be for one specific feature? .circle\#OpenLayers\.Geometry\.Point_111 ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with OpenLayers, but for a regular website this should work in most modern browsers. So if this isn't working, OpenLayers might not be supporting modern CSS3 features like this.

Comment: Right, good point. It might not be supporting CSS3 features like the color gradient. But are there any other possibilities than the color gradient using CSS?

Comment: You could try setting the background-color to black and on top of that set a background-image that's half purple, half transparent. You can convert the image to a data-url so you won't have to store it (http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker)

Comment: Another way would be to either use an extra element (which I guess isn't really possible in your case) or a pseudo-element (:before & :after)